# WordPress Migration - Find old root path?

Tags: sql, wordpress, database-migration

I am transferring a WP site using WP Migrate Pro and I'm stuck on the find and replace of the DB import. All I have is the folder containing the WP site, but I need to know the old file path, is there a way to find this? Possibly in the SQL file?

[image]

Comment: The SQL file should be plaintext, have you opened it and looked?

Comment: Yes, but it's massive and not immediately apparent where I would find the path.

Comment: Hi Tom, big fan. I've just searched a reasonably standard WP database, and there's no absolute path in it, at all. Have you tried removing that find/replace field? Or do you know for sure that it's necessary on your database? URL appears in wp_options, but that's all. I've migrated a lot of WP sites and I've never had to find/replace absolute paths